# Why React-router doesn't re-render the page and doesn't update the data when the url changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm building a project in React that retrieves data from an API through a custom hook, as soon as the data is retrieved, it shows cards that by clicking on them open the descriptive page. Up to here everything is ok.

```
// App.js
<Routes>
   <Route path="/" element={<Home />} /> // cards list
   <Route path="/:eleId" element={<Details />} /> // description page 
</Routes>

// Home.jsx with single card
<div className="container">
   <Link to={`/${eleId}`}>
      <Card />
   </Link>
</div>
```

My problem comes here:
inside the description page I have related links that open the same page when clicked but changing the data:

```
// Details.jsx description page 
import { useParams, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import useData from '../hooks/useData';

const Details = () => {
   const { eleId } = useParams(),
         [data] = useData(`alpha/${eleId}`); // call API with url of eleId

   return(
      <div className="description">
         <p>BLa bla bla</p>
         <Link to={`/${data.id}`}> Related </Link>
      </div>
   );
}

export default Details;
```

```
// useData.jsx custom hook
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useData = (param = 'all') => {
   const [data, setData] = useState([]),
         [error, setError] = useState(null),
         [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    
    const url = 'https://restcountries.com/v2/'+param;

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchAPI = async () => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            try {
                const response = await fetch(url),
                        json = await response.json();
                setData(json);
                setError(false);
            } catch(err) {
                setError(err.message);
                setData(null);
                console.log(err);
            }
            setIsLoading(false);
        };
        fetchAPI(); 
    }, []);

   return [data, error, isLoading];
}

export default useData;
```

the url changes correctly but the data does not update ... but if I refesh it updates.

I don't understand why React can't re-render the page. Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Thank you :)

Comment: Where do you define `eleId`?

Comment: can you show us the Details component

Comment: @norbitrial I define inside Details component with `useParams`

Comment: @VersifiXion ok i updated my question to add the details you asked me. thank you

Comment: `const [data] = useData(\`alpha/${eleId}\`);` looks like what you'd want, but whether it works or not depends on `useData` hook's implementation. Can you also add that custom hook code to your question? It may need to be updated to use the passed request path as a depedency.

Comment: @DrewReese done! added custom hook code, thanks :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for updating. It's exactly what I had suspected, you had an `useEffect` hook with a missing dependency. I've updated my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> // Details.jsx description page 
> <div className="description">
>   <p>BLa bla bla</p>
>   <Link to={`/${eleId}`}>Related</Link>
> <div>
> ```

If `Details` component is linking to itself, i.e. the route rendering it, this means the route path is already matched and rendering `Details`. `Details` may need to "listen" for changes on the `eleId` route match param. Use the `useParams` React hook to access the `eleId` param and an `useEffect` hook with `eleId` as a dependency to run any side-effect necessary when the param updates.

Example:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const Details = () => {

  const { eleId } = useParams();
  const [data] = useData(`alpha/${eleId}`);

  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    // Business logic to run when eleId updates
  }, [eleId]);

  ...
```

For the `useData` hook, move the `url` declaration into the `useEffect` hook and add the `param` argument as a dependency for the effect. When the param changes this will retrigger the `useEffect` and refetch data.

```
const useData = (param = 'all') => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    
  useEffect(() => {
    const url = 'https://restcountries.com/v2/' + param;

    const fetchAPI = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const json = await response.json();
        setData(json);
        setError(false);
      } catch(err) {
        setError(err.message);
        setData(null);
        console.log(err);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    fetchAPI(); 
  }, [param]);

  return [data, error, isLoading];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I hadn't thought about it at all ... maybe because I use the custom hook also inside `Details` to retrieve the details.

But how do I run the logic when eleId updates, I can't put a hook inside another hook.

Comment: I updated my question to add the details of  `Details` component

Comment: Now it works thank you so much! Initially I had put data in place of param and I didn't understand why it was wrong... but I never thought about putting param which is what updates. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Get the id from useparams and make the use effect that fetches the data sensitive to this id.